# Is there any way to cancel/stop/abort a getScript call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I've been looking about and there doesn't appear to be a way to actually abort/cancel/stop a script call once its made.

I find having to use lazy load to address a non-responsive script call to a third party kinda odd. With json/ajax, sure I can just timeout on it - great. But with a script call, no such luck. I figured jQuerys $.getScript would allow for such behavior. no?

**What I am hoping to accomplish**: cancel a blocking js call.

couldn't something like this work?

```
var getScript = $.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
     //
});

var exitOut = setTimeout(function(){
    getScript.abort();
},2000)
```

from what I've been reading a "script" request cannot be abort mid-stride.

BUT, since getScript is just an ajax call, I was hoping that timeout could also apply here. But some of my tests aren't bearing that out?

Any other solutions besides lazy loading?

Comment: Not clear what you are actually trying to do here, but once you've sent a request to a server, it's no longer in your hands. The server will process the request and provide a response regardless of whether or not you still care about that response. (unless the server itself provides some kind of cancellation mechanism).

Comment: thanks. I updated the original question with what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MattBurland That doesn't matter. jQuery AJAX promises have an `abort()` method that alerts jQuery to not process the response. The OP isn't worried about the server

Comment: @ian - so, from my research is that an incorrect assumption? That script calls cannot be aborted/cancelled midstride?

Comment: @jamesemanon I'm wondering if Bergi's answer is the solution. That `$.getScript()` calls are special

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> BUT, since getScript is just an ajax call, I was hoping that timeout could also apply here.

Actually, [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) does [not use XHR but a `<script>` element](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js#L32). Therefore, `abort` does not work and the `timeout` [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option does neither.

You might be better off with loading the script via XHR and then [manually evaling](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/) it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/test.js",
    dataType: "text",
    timeout: 2000
}).done(function(str) {
    $.globalEval(str);
});
```

Comment: ok, I'll give that a go. I wasn't aware of the nuances in regards to XHR and !XHR. thanks.