# Prevent "not responding" error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `$.getScript()` to fetch remote javascript. However, if the remote website is offline again and again, the Internet Explorer stops working and it gives "Not responding" error when you look at the process manager.

```
function fetch(url){
    window.setInterval(function (){
        $.getScript(url);
    },5000)
}

fetch("http://example.org/example.js");
```

I have also tried adding this into the function

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
```

But still I am getting the error. Is there anyway to throw the error for avoiding the browser stop working ?

Comment: Why use an interval to fetch a script more than once in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine `getScript()` spawns XHR and that runs indefinitely, and IE isn't smart enough to limit it. So you make new XHR every 5 seconds, which isn't very good, if you ask me. Maybe just dropping the interval would be good enough, if there's no specific reason for doing it this way.

There's then also bug that you'd get new copy of the same script every 5 seconds if the link works, not good either.

Try to find a way to set a timeout for it, or use another function, like `$.ajax()`, and create the script element by hand - or eval it. There you can set the timeout.

Also, this might be related: [22206566](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206566/is-there-any-way-to-cancel-stop-abort-a-getscript-call)